# How do I read two items at a time in a Perl foreach loop?

Tags: perl, loops

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
@list = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6);
foreach (@list) {
  #perl magic goes here 
  print "i: $i, j:$j\n";
}
```

returns:

```
i:1, j:2
i:3, j:4
i:5, j:6
```

In response to a very good suggestion below, I need to specify that this script will run on someone else's build server, and I'm not allowed to use any modules from CPAN.  Standard Perl only.

Comment: I would like to point out that in Perl 6 it would be `for @list -> $i, $j { say "i: $i, j:$j" }`

Comment: @BradGilbert  Addictive , can we predict that this will make its way into Perl5 ?  :-)  See also [Is it possible to assign two variables in Perl foreach loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29586827/2019415).

Comment: Not allowed to use any modules from CPAN? Why not? [Yes, even you can use CPAN](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=693828)!

Comment: Bottom are some ways how to resolve your problem. Test some of them, and check RAM utilization with big source array. btw. conversion array into has isn't so good idea.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I believe the proper way to do this is to use natatime, from [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils):

from the docs:

> natatime BLOCK LIST
>
> Creates an array iterator, for looping over an array in chunks of `$n` items
>       at a time. (`n` at a time, get it?). An example is probably a better 
>       explanation than I could give in words.

Example:

```
 my @x = ('a' .. 'g');
 my $it = natatime 3, @x;
 while (my @vals = $it->())
 {
     print "@vals\n";
 }
```

This prints

```
a b c
d e f
g
```

The implementation of [`List::MoreUtils::natatime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils):

```
sub natatime ($@)
{
    my $n = shift;
    my @list = @_;

    return sub
    {
        return splice @list, 0, $n;
    }
}
```

Comment: This rocks. Anything is better than a c-style for-loop, but this is MUCH better.

Comment: I've gotta get that off of CPAN, don't I?

Sad to say that this script runs on a build server I don't own.

That's really nice though, thank you.

Comment: As an other comment states, it's one of the "very-perlish" answer: "grab a module" ;--)
so to be complete: 

use List::MoreUtils qw(natatime);

my @list = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6);

my $it = natatime 2, @list;
while( my( $i, $j)= $it->()) {
  print "i: $i, j:$j\n";
}

Comment: You don't have to install it system-wide necessarily. You can just copy it locally, or even just grab the code (look at http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/VPARSEVAL/List-MoreUtils-0.22/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm ) it's super-short!

Comment: Notice that there is little bit difference between foreach and natatime. foreach is faster and less memory consuming (doesn't copy array as natatime does internally) and allow array members modification e.g foreach my $a (@x) { $a++ } is same as $_++ foreach @x

Comment: natatime wouldn't need to copy the list if it did: my $list = \@_; then later: splice @$list, 0, $n;

Comment: this procedure will be bad with 2 ways: 1, it make copy of @_, then working with big array will consume big RAM. 2, when you replace @list by @_, then source array will be dectructed.

Comment: @Znik: working with a big array was not listed in the problem description. You know what they say about premature optimization... ;--)

Comment: @Znik - No, the source array is not destroyed, just the copy of it in the subroutine.

Comment: Your opinion produces bugs similar to File::Find and File::Find::Rules . Author didn't look ahead, then in iterator mode, it defines very big array when you scan big directory structure.  For resolve this issue as I explained, I inserted my working code. It is not too complicated :)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/569812/2261349  and it beaves similar like my%hash=qw(1 2 3 4 5), where 5th element is ignored. My code do the same, preventing hidden bugs.

Answer (score 21):

I'd use splice.

```
my @list = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6);
while(my ($i,$j) = splice(@list,0,2)) {
  print "i: $i, j: $j\n";
}
```

Comment: As noted on another answer, this is also list-destructive. The non-destructive answer would involve a for loop with indexes and doing index + 1.

Comment: That's my choice too, if I didn't care about destroying the list. +1.

Comment: If list destruction is a problem, you can just copy the list beforehand. You can even do it inside a { block } so it falls out of scope when you're done: { my @temp = @list; while(my ($i, $j) = splice(@list,0,2)) { print "i: $i, j: $j\n"; } }

Comment: @ChrisLutz ++ as @mirod points out this is how `List::MoreUtils` `natatime` implements this as well.

Answer (score 18):

I think you'd want to do this differently.
Try this:

```
while (scalar(@list) > 0) {
    $i = shift(@list);
    $j = shift(@list);
    print "i: $i, j:$j\n";
}
```

Keep in mind that this will destroy the list, but it will work for that little loop.

Comment: This is list-destructive.  Huge difference on his request

Comment: @cmartin, nothing in his request suggests that it can't use up the list. So, list-destructive actions might fit the bill. But, if that's the case, there's no reason to shift-shift, just splice.

Comment: I didn't test, but doesn't the second shift fail when there are an odd number of elements in @list?  But what's an odd undef among friends. ;-)

Comment: this is destructive as other examples, but you should correct it by  (scalar(@list)>1) for prevent fetching last unpaired element.

Answer (score 16):

#### Set up some test data, and import [`say`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Modern::Perl):

```
use Modern::Perl;
use List::AllUtils qw'zip';

my @array = zip @{['a'..'z']}, @{[1..26]} ;
```

#### Simple looping using an increment variable.

```
    {
      my $i = 0;
      while(
        (my($a,$b) = @array[$i++,$i++]),
        $i <= @array # boolean test
      ){
        say "$a => $b";
      }
    }
```

#### Looping over pairs using [`List::Pairwise`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Pairwise)  [`(pair)`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Pairwise#pair).

```
    use List::Pairwise qw'pair';

    for my $pair (pair @array){
      my($a,$b) = @$pair;

      say "$a => $b";
    }
```

#### Looping over array 2 at a time, using [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils)  [`(natatime)`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils#natatime).

```
    use List::AllUtils qw'natatime';

    my $iter = natatime 2, @array;
    while( my($a,$b) = $iter->() ){
      say "$a => $b";
    }
```

#### Coerce it into a hash, and loop over the keys. Useful if you don't care about the order.

```
    {
      my %map = @array;
      for my $key (keys %map){
        my $value = $map{$key};
        say "$key => $value";
      }
    }
```

Comment: useful if you're injesting pairwise from an array for a subroutine

`@array = qw/michael tan kelly wong/`, 
`sub aFunc($a, $b){say $a, $b}`, 
`aFunc(@$_) for (pair @array)`

Comment: A pairs function is now available in List::Util, which is a core module.

Answer (score 11):

The closest equivalent is, unfortunately, going old-school:

```
for(my $ix = 0; $ix <= $#list; $ix += 2) {
    my $i = $list[$ix];
    my $j = $list[$ix + 1];
    print "i: $i, j:$j\n";
}
```

I like Jack M's answer better, really, though I would write it in sexier Perl:

```
while(@list) {
    my $i = shift @list;
    my $j = shift @list;
    print "i: $i, j:$j\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 for the standard for() loop.  Some control structures are a classic because they work =).

Comment: @jrockway, who edited $ix <= $#list to $ix < @list so SO's syntax highlighting would work better: I know you mean well, but the idea of changing the actual content (not formatting) of code so a Web site displays it better inspires me to great violence.

Comment: @chaos - from @jrockway's edit comment, the change wasn't for syntax highlighting, it was for readability and "idiomatic-ness".  It works just the same and has two less punctuation marks.  How can you argue with that? :-)

Comment: He said it was to 'fix markdown markup', which is kind of unclear since Markdown as such isn't involved, but the nearest thing that seemed to have anything to do with it was the # being interpreted as a comment.

Comment: Anyway, I don't really accept the alternate version as 'more idiomatic'.  Two characters shorter is something I'll usually go for, but for whatever crotchety reason, in this case since Perl lets me say exactly what I mean, I'd rather do that at the cost of two characters.

Comment: I never actually use $#array to get the last element of the array. So I prefer $ix < @list.

Comment: That is certainly your privilege, sir.

Comment: To clarify: $array[$#array] is the last element (same as $array[-1]), not $#array.

Answer (score 8):

Perl v5.36 added the experimental `for_list` that allows you to iterate over multiple items at the same time:

```
use v5.36;
use experimental qw(for_list);

my @array = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6);
for my( $i, $j ) ( @array ) {
    say "i:$i, j:$j";
    }
```

## Prior to v5.36

If I only could use standard Perl with no modules, I'd probably drop down to a C-style for loop that counts by 2:

```
for( my $i = 0; $i < @array; $i += 2 ) {
    my( $j, $k ) = @array[ $i, $i+1 ];
    ...
    }
```

If you have an odd number of elements, you'll have to decide how to handle an extra element. Your problem may not care that you get an extra element that is undefined since you specifically need pairs.

Simply reading past the end of an array does not change the array, so that part is fine.

If you must have pairs, a simple tactic might be to add an appropriate value to the end of the array so you always end up with pairs. Likewise, you can remove the last element (or whichever element) to end up with an even number again. Those depend on your problem.

Otherwise, you're doing slightly more work:

```
for( my $i = 0; $i < @array; $i += 2 ) {
    push @pair, $array[$i];
    push @pair, $array[$i+1] if $i+1 <= $#array;
    ... 
    }
```

However, if you wanted something fancy from one of the modules you can't use, you can just add that module to your code. If you can write code, you can use modules. You might just have to include the module with all of the code you deliver while you set `@INC` appropriately. This is the basic idea of [inc::Module::Install](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Install) and [PAR](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR).

I spend a lot of my time working with a build system that creates its own CPAN repository, installs its dependencies from its private CPAN, and then tests code. Having a build farm doesn't preclude using modules; it's local policy that does. However, that might not make sense in all cases even though it's possible.

Comment: for case with odd elements in array, it will get last unpaired element, and as second vallue this will add undef to pair.

Comment: Is the ampersand-lt-semicolon in the first code example HTML?  It doesn't look like perl.

Answer (score 6):

Risking the necromancy tag, I decided to add one more from Tim Toady's backpack:

```
for (0 .. $#list) {
    next if $_ % 2;
    my ($i, $j) = @list[$_, $_ + 1];
    say "i:$i, j:$j";
}
```

Nondestructive, no duplicate lists, no state variables and reasonably terse.

Answer (score 4):

You will probably want to create a simple subroutine to make it work for you.

I suggest this:

```
{
  my $cl_ind = 0;
  sub arrayeach(@) {
    my @obj = @_;
    if(($cl_ind+2) > @obj)
    {
      $cl_ind = 0;
      return;
    }
    $cl_ind+=2;
    return ($obj[$cl_ind-2],$obj[$cl_ind-1]);
  }
}
```

The closure makes it work cleanly.  To use arrayeach (which works like the hash each without requiring dangerous coercion to an array:

```
my @temp = (1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6);
while( ($a,$b) = arrayeach(@temp)) {
  print "A $a AND $b\n";
}
```

This is nondestructive.

Comment: And what happen if I want consume two array in parallel?

Comment: That wasn't the question.  But it's wonderful to see I have more negative points than solutions that are generally considered "worse".

Answer (score 3):

How about a general purpose functional solution.

```
use Carp; # so mapn can croak about errors

sub mapn (&$@) {
    my ($sub, $n, @ret) = splice @_, 0, 2;
    croak '$_[1] must be >= 1' unless $n >= 1;
    while (@_) {
        local *_ = \$_[0];
        push @ret, $sub->(splice @_, 0, $n)
    }
    @ret
}

sub by ($@) {mapn {[@_]} shift, @_}
sub every ($@); *every = \&by;
```

The `mapn` function works just like `map`, except the first argument after its block is the number of elements to take.  It places the first element in   `$_`  and all of the elements in  `@_` .

```
print mapn {"@_\n"} 2 => 1 .. 5;
# prints
1 2
3 4
5
```

The next two identical subs, `by` and `every` create useful adverbs for the various looping constructs. They process the list with mapn, and return a list of array refs of the desired size

```
print "@$_\n" for every 2 => 1..10;

print map {"@$_\n"} grep {$_->[1] > 5} by 2 => 1..10;
```

I find this to be a cleaner and more intuitive solution than natatime, or other one off solutions like a c style for loop.

Comment: This is really nice - I like the look and feel of short "adverb" type subroutines that chain into short but powerful statements/expressions like this. And thanks for [`List::Gen`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Gen) - it brings that stylish power to the masses ;-)

Comment: there is only one mistake. when we assign %hash=@array, then last unpaired element will be ignored. In your solution, this will be used with added undef as its pair.

Answer (score 3):

```
my $i;
for ( qw(a b c d) ) {
    if (!defined($i)) { $i = $_; next; }
    print STDOUT "i = $i, j = $_\n";
    undef($i);
}
```

Outputs:

```
i = a, j = b
i = c, j = d
```

It also works for lists, not only for arrays.

Comment: what for undef($i) ? simply wrap this inside do {} then my $i will be local variable.

Answer (score 2):

As Mirod explains, there isn't much code to it. Here's pretty much all you would need. (Note that I don't have any checks for odd-numbered lists or the like.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = qw/1 2 3 4 5 6/;
my $get_em = get_by(2, @list);

while ( my ($i, $j) = $get_em->() ) {
  print "i: $i, j: $j\n";
}

sub get_by {
  my $n = shift;
  my @list = @_;

  return sub {
    return splice @list, 0, $n;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

quick solution for small arrays:

```
for ( map {$_*2} 0..@list/2-1 ){
    my ($i, $j) = @list[$_,$_+1];
    print "i: $i, j:$j\n";
}
```

some kind oneliner

data:

```
@v = (a=>1, b=>2, c=>3);
```

this

```
print join ', ', map{sprintf '%s:%s', $v[$_], $v[$_+1]} grep {!($_%2)} 0..$#v
```

or somthing like this

```
print join ', ', map {sprintf '%s:%s', @v[$_,$_+1]} map {$_*2} 0..@v/2-1;
```

result is same

```
a:1, b:2, c:3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop would do what you need.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = qw(1 2 3 4 5 );
my $i = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < scalar(@list); $i++)
{
    my $a = $list[$i];
    my $b = $list[++$i];
    if(defined($a)) {
        print "a:$a";
    }
    if(defined($b)) {
        print "b:$b";
    }   
    print "\n";
}
```

**edit**: I corrected my post to use the scalar function to retrieve the size of the array and also add some checking in case the array does not contain an even number of elements.

Comment: you do not need use scalar, because comparator get arguments in scalar context. then \@list will be automatically converted into number of array elements.

Answer (score 1):

another approach, not fully clean, but usable.  each creates iterator, you can use it twice. when parameter is classic array, it returns index and value, please read this: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html

so, your code can be like this:

```
my @array=qw(one two three four five); #five element as unpaired will be ignored
while (my ($i1,$one,$i2,$two)=(each(@array),each(@array)) {
  #we will use $ix for detect end of array
  next unless defined $i1 and defined $i2; #secure complete end of array
  print "fetched array elements: $one => $two\n";
};
```

Example above will not destruct source data, against shift or similar.
I hope this we helpful for anyone. of course case with plain iterator is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this code to solve a similar requirement:

```
sub map_pairs(&\@) {
    my $op = shift;
    use vars '@array';
    local *array = shift;    # make alias of calling array

    return () unless @array;

    # Get package global $a, $b for the calling scope
    my ($caller_a, $caller_b) = do {
        my $pkg = caller();
        no strict 'refs';
        \*{$pkg.'::a'}, \*{$pkg.'::b'};
    };

    # Get index counter size.
    my $limit = $#array/2;

    # Localize caller's $a and $b
    local(*$caller_a, *$caller_b);

    # This map is also the return value
    map {
        # assign to $a, $b as refs to caller's array elements
        (*$caller_a, *$caller_b) = \($array[$_], $array[$_+1]);
        $op->();    # perform the transformation
    } 
    map { 2 * $_ } 0..$limit;  # get indexes to operate upon.
}
```

You use it like so:

```
@foo = qw( a 1 b 2 c 3 );
my @bar = map_pairs { "$a is $b" } @foo;
```

to get:

```
@bar = ( 'a is 1', 'b is 2', 'c is 3' );
```

I've been meaning to submit to the maintainer of List::MoreUtils, but I don't have an XS version to offer.

Answer (score 0):

here's an implementation of natatime that doesn't make a copy of the list:

```
sub natatime {
  my $n = shift;
  my $list = \@_;

  sub {
    return splice @$list, 0, $n;
  }
}

my $it = natatime(3, qw(1 2 3 4 5 6));
while ( my @list = $it->() ) {
  print "@list\n";
}
```

Comment: this function will destruct source array. when you swap qw(1 2 3 4 5 6) by any other variable, you will lost data strored on it.

Comment: @Znik - No, it won't. Try it, or give me an example of what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done non-destructively, with [Eric Strom's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189416/eric-strom) simply fantastic [`List::Gen`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Gen):

```
perl -MList::Gen=":utility" -E '@nums = "1" .. "6" ; 
      say "i:$_->[0] j:$_->[1]" for every 2 => @nums'
```

**Output**:

```
i:1 j:2 
i:3 j:4 
i:5 j:6
```

**Edit** (add a CPAN-less version):

Array slices and C-style for loop *à la* [brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/570914/2019415) and [Tom Christiansen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29590758/2019415)! This can be read as "use an index (`$i`) to loop through a `@list` `foreach` `$n` elements at a time":

```
use v5.16; # for strict, warnings, say

my @list = "1" .. "6";
my $n = 2 ;   # the number to loop by
$n-- ;        # subtract 1 because of zero index

foreach (my $i = 0 ; $i < @list ; $i += $n ) { 
  say "i:", [ @list[$i..$i+$n] ]->[0], " j:", [ @list[$i..$i+$n] ]->[1];
  $i++ ;          
}
```

We access the results as elements (`->[0]`) of an anonymous array (`[ ]`).  For more generic output the interpolated array slice could be used on its own, *e.g.*: `print "@list[$i..$i+$n]";` changing the value of `$n` as required.

Answer (score 0):

Divide number of elements by two, iterate by one.  Print index and next:

```
print "i:$list[$_*2], j:$list[$_*2+1]\n" for 0..$#list/2;
```

Or if you want a full block:

```
foreach my $i ( 0..$#list/2 ) { print "i:$list[$i*2], j:$list[$i*2+1]\n"; }
```

Or:

```
foreach my $n ( 0..$#list/2 ) { 
    my ($i,$j) = @list[$n*2,$n*2+1];
    print "i:$i, j:$j\n"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) includes [`pairs`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) since version 1.29, included as Perl core module since Perl v5.19.3. So at least with Perl >= 5.20 you can safely use:

```perl
use List::Util qw(pairs);

@list = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6);
foreach (pairs @list) {
  my ($i, $j) = @$_;
  print "i: $i, j:$j\n";
}
```

And since Perl v5.21.1 more readable:

```perl
use List::Util qw(pairs);

@list = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6);
foreach (pairs @list) {
  my ($i, $j) = ($_->key, $_->value);
  print "i: $i, j:$j\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

<s>I think more simpler way is to use old poor 'each'.
Straight like this:</s>

```
while (my ($key,$value) = each @list) {
        print "$key=$value\n";
}
```

Updated:

Yes, it's wrong. One should convert list to hash first but it could be too exensive:

```
my %hash = (@list);
while (my ($key,$value) = each %hash) {
        print "$key=$value\n";
}
```

Comment: Good to point out that `each` works with arrays (from perl-5.12 onward) but it returns "index and value" so `perl  -E '@n = "1" .. "6" ; while ( ($i, $j ) = each @n ) { say "i:$i j:$j" } ` gives: `i:0 j:1 ... i:5 j:6` instead of two at a time. Can you think of a way to make your post more correct ?

Comment: with this update, for odd elements will be repeated, only one pair for this will be saved. for example, for array:  qw(one two one three), you will lost one pair, probably only last pair in collision will be saved in this hash.

Answer (score -1):

```
while ($#rec>0) {
  my($a,$b) = ( shift(@rec), shift(@rec) );
  print "($a,$b)\n";
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: The @rec with shift would mess with the original contents especially down stream in the code