# Perl: I need to join elements of an array in sets of two in order to sort output by frequency

Tags: perl

Let me know if I have to make this more concise, if you don't have time, just answer the question above and skip the following words:

I just wanted you to fully understand the problem. THANKS A LOT in advance.

BACKGROUND: I am making search engine (this is only a small part of the code... so it may be sensitive to change... not your problem). The search engine has to ouput all the sentences meeting a certain criteria. So if the sentence includes the right terms, it will be placed under a sub heading which is under a larger heading(in caps). The caps heading is sorted by alphabetical. I want the sub headings sorted by frequency.

OBJECTIVE: I thought of sorting by frequency by joining all the corresponding matches to the subheading, and then which every  sub heading element is largest goes first. HOW DO I DO THIS? (Ex. $array[0] and $array[1] need to be concatenated)

APOLOGY: I am new to Perl and this site, so I'm not sure if this format is too long... I am sure and sorry that my code is crude, but it works

HERE WE GO:

LEGEND1: $sortedallgramfunc is of the form: XCOMP

LEGEND2: $headmatches (the subheading) is of the form: *xcomp* of expend is:  move

LEGEND3: $sentmatches is of the form: MATCH #1 Sent. 29
To  acquire  these  organic  molecules  ,  animals  must   --expend-- energy  to   **move**  themselves

If the subheading has MATCH #2 as well, it and all the sentences associated, should be printed before a subheading with only 1 match

```
foreach my $sortedallgramfunc (@sortedallgramfunc) {
my @sepmatches; ## MOVED DOWN HERE TO TEST, MAYBE MOVE BACK depending on sol'n
print ("\n",uc $sortedallgramfunc,"\n\n");# Which gramfunc is being shown?

for (my $l=0; $l <= @headmatches; $l++) {
    if (defined( $headmatches[$l] ) and $headmatches[$l] =~ /$sortedallgramfunc/) {

        unless ($seenmatches{ $headmatches[$l] }++) {
            push (@sepmatches, $headmatches[$l]);
            my $count = 1;
            my @allsents; ## use for all sents that go under heading, add to heading to get @allmatches
            for (my $m=0; $m <= @sentmatches; $m++) {
                if ( defined( $sentmatches[$m]) and $sentmatches[$m] =~ /\s\S\S$firstmatches[$l]\S\S\s/ and $sentmatches[$m] =~ /\s\S\S$secondmatches[$l]\S\S\s/) { ##We know $l and $m are matching

                    push (@allsents, "MATCH #$count $sentmatches[$m]"); # unless $seens{ $sentmatches[$m] }++);
                    $count++;

                }
            }
            push (@sepmatches, @allsents);

            ##$sepmatches[0] is header, [1] is all sentences etc. EVEN - header, ODD - sent
            ## NOW WANT TO join headers and sentences (0 and 1 etc.) in @allmatches<====
             # SO I can us the following line to hopefully sort by frequency of matches under each subheading: @sortedallmatches = sort {length $a cmp length $b } @allmatches;

        }
    }
}print @sepmatches;
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you actually asked a question in there.  Also, providing a test case or two plus a simple wrapper which calls your function would help anyone willing to dig down deep.  And yes, using another hash is typically the way one would solve lines appearing twice.  The hash could be a tactical one (per line) instead of saved, of course.

Comment: @Seth Thanks, I put the question with the objective. To be honest, I don't understand calling the function part... i have no functions, before this loop is a huge for loop containing more for loops... I guess a separate function would be WAY better. I will work on that and I will try and think of a test case.

Comment: I just joined by join ('', @sepmatches)... for now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely want List::MoreUtil's natatime. This is a duplicate of many other questions along the same lines, such as [How do I read two items at a time in a Perl foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569772/how-do-i-read-two-items-at-a-time-in-a-perl-foreach-loop).

Comment: Oh, I read that earlier for another part, never thought to use it here... haven't used :: before though lol. Thanks, I'll see what I can do.