# how to use three objects of an array at a time in php

Tags: php

I have an array called emp_rec with more than 100 employees and each employee having around 60 fields, am using the following method to use one employee at a time...

```
foreach($emp_rec as $obj) {
   $name = $obj->get_empname();
  //.....
  ......///
}
```

Now am planning to use three employees at a time in a single loop,
How can i do this...?

Comment: does this three means previous - current - next objects?

Comment: Here three means first second and third.....

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569772/how-do-i-read-two-items-at-a-time-in-a-perl-foreach-loop

Comment: `foreach (array_chunk($emp_rec, 3) as $chunk) {` see: [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: Try the method @Yoshi is giving.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$current = Array();
while(($current[0] = array_shift($emp_rec))
   && ($current[1] = array_shift($emp_rec))
   && ($current[2] = array_shift($emp_rec))) {
  // do stuff here
}
if( $current[0]) {
    // there were records left over, optionally do something with them.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($emp_rec); $i+=3) {
    $emp1 = $emp_rec[$i];
    $emp2 = $emp_rec[$i+1];
    $emp3 = $emp_rec[$i+2];
}
```

Comment: I tried this but its not working because its not an array, its array of objects and each object having 50 elements...

Comment: An array of objects is still an array and can be treated as one. Do you mean to say that it's an object that has an attribute with an array of objects? You can check out the ArrayAccess interface, it seems to fit your requirements ( http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php )

Comment: You are not increasing $i in your statement.

Comment: I am, it's a `for`, so the `$i+=3` is executed at the end of each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can iterate in one time on same multi objects. Easy to adapt.

```
<?php
// Example of class
class A {
    public $a = 'a';
    public $b = 'b';
    public $c = 'c';
}

$obj1 = new A; // Instantiate 3 objects
$obj2 = new A;
$obj3 = new A;

$objs = array((array)$obj1, (array)$obj2, (array)$obj3); // Array of objects (cast in array)

foreach ($objs[0] as $key => $value) {
    echo $objs[0][$key];
    echo $objs[1][$key];
    echo $objs[2][$key];
}
```

Output `aaabbbccc`

Comment: I have executed this script, it gives output like this a a a b b b c c c.... This is not am looking for, i need a b c at a time....

Comment: Ok sorry, I have misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
$GROUP_SIZE = 3;

$emp_count = count($emp_rec);
for ($i=0; $i<$emp_count; $i+=$GROUP_SIZE) {
    for ($j=0; $i+$j<$emp_count && $j<$GROUP_SIZE; $j++) {
        $current = $emp_rec[$i+$j];
        $name = $current->get_empname();
    }
}
```

If you need to manipulate 3 or N employees at a time, it would let you know in which "group" the current employee is.